# ScriptableObject creating 'non' list of dashes in CreateAssetMenu

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a pallette ScriptableObject for which the code is below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace UnityForge
{
    [CreateAssetMenu ( fileName = "NewTerrainPallette", menuName = "DwarvenGear/Forge/", order = 0 )]
    public class TerrainPallette : ScriptableObject, IList<TerrainColor>, IEnumerable<TerrainColor>
    {
        #region Fields
        [SerializeField] private List<TerrainColor> m_TerrainColors = new List<TerrainColor> ();
        #endregion
        #region Properties
        public TerrainColor this [string name]
        {
            get
            {
                foreach ( TerrainColor terrainColor in m_TerrainColors )
                    if ( terrainColor.Name == name )
                        return terrainColor;
                return new TerrainColor ( "BLANK", Color.black );
            }
            set
            {
                for ( int i = 0; i < m_TerrainColors.Count; i++ )
                    if ( m_TerrainColors [i].Name == name )
                        m_TerrainColors [i] = value;
            }
        }
        public TerrainColor this [int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if ( index < m_TerrainColors.Count )
                    return m_TerrainColors [index];
                return new TerrainColor ( "BLANK", Color.black );
            }
            set
            {
                m_TerrainColors [index] = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Constructors
        public TerrainPallette ()
        {
            m_TerrainColors = new List<TerrainColor> ();
        }
        #endregion
        #region IEnumerable
        public IEnumerator<TerrainColor> GetEnumerator () => m_TerrainColors.GetEnumerator ();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator () => m_TerrainColors.GetEnumerator ();
        #endregion
        #region IList
        public int Count { get { return m_TerrainColors.Count; } }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
        public void Add ( TerrainColor item ) => m_TerrainColors.Add ( item );
        public void Add ( string name, Color color ) => m_TerrainColors.Add ( new TerrainColor ( name, color ) );
        public void Clear () => m_TerrainColors.Clear ();
        public bool Contains ( TerrainColor item ) => m_TerrainColors.Contains ( item );
        public bool Contains ( string name )
        {
            foreach ( TerrainColor terrainColor in m_TerrainColors )
                if ( terrainColor.Name == name )
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
        public void CopyTo ( TerrainColor [] array ) => m_TerrainColors.CopyTo ( array );
        public void CopyTo ( TerrainColor [] array, int arrayIndex ) => m_TerrainColors.CopyTo ( array, arrayIndex );
        public void CopyTo ( int index, TerrainColor [] array, int arrayIndex, int count ) => m_TerrainColors.CopyTo ( index, array, arrayIndex, count );
        public int IndexOf ( TerrainColor item ) => m_TerrainColors.IndexOf ( item );
        public int IndexOf ( TerrainColor item, int index ) => m_TerrainColors.IndexOf ( item, index );
        public int IndexOf ( TerrainColor item, int index, int count ) => m_TerrainColors.IndexOf ( item, index, count );
        public int IndexOf ( string name )
        {
            foreach ( TerrainColor terrainColor in m_TerrainColors )
                if ( terrainColor.Name == name )
                    return m_TerrainColors.IndexOf ( terrainColor );
            return -1;
        }
        public void Insert ( int index, TerrainColor item ) => m_TerrainColors.Insert ( index, item );
        public void Insert ( int index, string name, Color color ) => m_TerrainColors.Insert ( index, new TerrainColor ( name, color ) );
        public void RemoveAt ( int index ) => m_TerrainColors.RemoveAt ( index );
        public bool Remove ( TerrainColor item ) => m_TerrainColors.Remove ( item );
        public bool Remove ( string name )
        {
            foreach ( TerrainColor terrainColor in m_TerrainColors )
                if ( terrainColor.Name == name )
                    return m_TerrainColors.Remove ( terrainColor );
            return false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

But when I go to create the Pallette I get this in the menu

[image]

There are no other ScriptableObjects in my code right now, and Unity isn't throwing any errors, otherwise I'd be able to pick out the problem code. Is there something I'm missing? This is the full code, but I have tried removing the indexers, the constructor, the IEnumerable inheritance as well as the code and same with the IList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove last dash in "DwarvenGear/Forge/"

```
[CreateAssetMenu ( fileName = "NewTerrainPallette", menuName = "DwarvenGear/Forge", order = 0 )]
```

Comment: As I had realized, while yes your solution would certainly work (though not for the required effect), the answer to my question was that I had somehow neglected to put "Tile Pallette" after the "Forge/".